# How to disable constraint at run time in ios?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uikit, nslayoutconstraint

I am having a view which is further having some text fields.  I have set the aspect ratio of the view with self & its super view.  Now when I click the text field then keyboard appears I am resizing the view & setting its y position as well so that keyboard does not cover the textfields.  I am using below code for that.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    /* keyboard is visible, move views */
    if([textField isEqual:self.txt_twitter] || [textField isEqual:self.txt_linkedin])
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1f animations:^
         {
             CGRect rect = self.view.frame;

             // 1. move the view's origin up so that the text field that will be hidden come above the keyboard
             // 2. increase the size of the view so that the area behind the keyboard is covered up.
             rect.origin.y -= 130;
            rect.size.height += 130;
             self.view.frame = rect;



         }];
    }

}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    /* resign first responder, hide keyboard, move views */
    /* keyboard is visible, move views */
    if([textField isEqual:self.txt_twitter] || [textField isEqual:self.txt_linkedin])
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1f animations:^
         {
             CGRect rect = self.view.frame;

             // revert back to the normal state.
             rect.origin.y += 130;
             rect.size.height -= 130;


             self.view.frame = rect;


         }];

    }

}
```

Now when my view height increase then it's width also increase because I have set the constraints for that.  Please tell me how can I resolve this issue.  In this case I don't want to increase the width of my view.

Comment: Either use autolayout completely or don't use it at all.  You shouldn't be manually editing frames of views controlled by autolayout.

Answer (score 3):

Mixing Autolayout constraints and direct frame manipulation is a bad idea in general, you probably should avoid this. I would suggest you make some IBOutlets for height or position constraints of the views you want to move/resize and change constraint.constant in your delegate callbacks instead of changing frames.

Also, when handling keyboard events it's better to listen for keyboard notifications (`UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`) instead of using text field delegate methods.

Added a gif to illustrate better -

[image]

Some code from the project:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self addKeyboardNotificationsObserver];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)addKeyboardNotificationsObserver {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(handleKeyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(handleKeyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}

- (void)handleKeyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)paramNotification

{

    NSDictionary* info = [paramNotification userInfo];

    //when switching languages keyboard might change its height (emoji keyboard is higher than most keyboards).
    //You can get both sizes of the previous keyboard and the new one from info dictionary.

    // size of the keyb that is about to disappear
    __unused CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    // size of the keyb that is about to appear
    CGSize kbSizeNew = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    //make adjustments to constraints here...

    self.redSquareBottomConstraint.constant = kbSizeNew.height;

    //and this is where magic happens!

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

}

- (void)handleKeyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)paramNotification

{
    //adjust constraints

    self.redSquareBottomConstraint.constant = 0;

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

}

- (void)dealloc {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

}
```

As you can see from the code, we extract keyboard's size from the userInfo dictionary that comes with the notification. As pointed out by  **nhgrif**, you can extract some other valuable information from it, like the duration (key - `UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey`) or curve (key - `UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey`) of the animation when keyboard appears/dissapers. Docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Keyboard_Notification_User_Info_Keys). If you want specific animation behaviour you can wrap layout call in animation block like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                 animations:^{

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

}];
```

Comment: Best answer.  This is exactly how I do it.  We don't need to add or remove any constraints or set any content-insets (as some do with scroll views and scroll view subclasses).  Just set a constraint to the bottom edge and set its constant when the keyboard appears/disappears.  My only complaint about this answer is that we're not animating the change with they keyboard as we should be.

Comment: @nhgrif It actually does animate :-)  If you want, you can wrap `-layoutIfNeeded` in one of the UIView animation blocks to achieve specific animation timing and behaviour.

Comment: That's what I'm saying.  We haven't extracted the animation duration or the animation curve out of the notification info, which we should be doing.  That's my only complaint about this answer.

Comment: @nhgrif updated my answer with some more info on that matter. For some reason layout happens with the exact animation parameters as keyboard animation has even without the animation block. It's something I've noticed accidentally and still use. Not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score -3):

just make IBOutlet for Width constraint and reassign it when changing frame' height!!

Comment: This question is asking *how* to do things as such.

Comment: so that is what i said, i consider my answer is pretty much clear to  @deepk kumar